# Jquery: form.submit() works but form.submit(handler) doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have only one form in my html.

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="WebToLeadForm" action="http://Sujay-Y510p:80/suitecrm/index.php?entryPoint=WebToLeadCapture" method="POST" name="WebToLeadForm">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-group form-control-group form-md-line-input">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="form_control_1">Salutation</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="salutation" name="salutation">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                    <option value="">Ms</option>
                    <option value="">Mr</option>
                    <option value="">Mrs</option>
                    <option value="">Doctor</option>
                    <option value="">Prof</option>
                </select>
                <div class="form-control-focus">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="name">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text" name="first_name">
                <div class="form-control-focus">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="form_control_1">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text">
                <div class="form-control-focus">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="form_control_1">Mobile</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="phone_mobile" name="phone_mobile" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text">
                <div class="form-control-focus">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="form_control_1">Email Address</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" onchange="validateEmailAdd();">
                <div class="form-control-focus">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="button" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn blue" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <tr>
        <td style="display: none;">
            <input id="campaign_id" type="hidden" name="campaign_id" value="34101a86-12b1-bec3-2c18-560ed4c48ddb" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="display: none;">
            <input id="assigned_user_id" type="hidden" name="assigned_user_id" value="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="display: none;">
            <input id="req_id" type="hidden" name="req_id" value="last_name;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

In my script when I write the below mentioned code it submits properly. It takes me to the response page.

```
$('form').submit();
```

but when I write the below code it doesn't even enter the function. No submit takes place. It doesn't even display the alert.

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('inside');
});
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: the first one is a function call. the 2nd one is function handler override.

Comment: Do you see the alert ('inside') triggered?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Shouldn't the second function at least display the alert?

Comment: @enkrates I don't even see the alert

Comment: @lemonTea let me explain myself: in your first script you are calling the submit function. in your 2nd script you are telling jquery what to do if the submit is called, but you are **not calling the function**. you are just **overriding it**

Comment: @Banana That means I should define this elsewhere and invoke it wherever I want it ? Will that then invoke whatever I put inside the function? I'm a bit new to this so forgive me if I don't get it right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you call:

```
$('form').submit();
```

in simple words, it tells jquery **"please submit the form"**

when you call this however:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('inside');
});
```

it tells jquery: **"in case the form is submitted, run this function"**

meaning:

the first script calls the submission, while the 2nd script attaches a handler to the submission event **but does not call the submission**

if in addition to attaching the handler, you want to submit the form then you need to call the submit without arguments in it after:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('inside');
});
$('form').submit();
```

the same works similarly with other jquery functions, click, load, etc.
without arguments its an invokation, while with a function it is simply a handler attaching without invokation.

Comment: This has solved my issue. I'm not sure why the downvote. I'm upvoting this.

Comment: @lemonTea I had given the same explanation, but I don't understand why you accepted this. Check out my answer again, just see it.

Comment: @Banana I was not the one who down-voted your answer, if you wanna know, I have even corrected the answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, i never said you did. by the way, you answer answers several completely different issues and not what op was asking...

Comment: @PraveenKumar Banana was the first to point out the issue of overriding vs calling. Besides, I wanted to know how do I get program control into the overridden method which Banana showed first. Sorry if my question was not clear at the beginning. But I appreciate your help. thanks.

Comment: @Banana Was saying out of curiosity.. `:P`

Comment: @lemonTea Yup... Your question was not that clear.. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I guess I got your issue. You don't have a `submitButton` to process the submission of the form.

```
<button type="button" class="btn blue" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

Change the above code to:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn blue" id="submitButton" />
```

#### Working Snippet

```js
$('form').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('inside');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="WebToLeadForm" action="http://Sujay-Y510p:80/suitecrm/index.php?entryPoint=WebToLeadCapture" method="POST" name="WebToLeadForm">
  <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group form-control-group form-md-line-input">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="form_control_1">Salutation</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="salutation" name="salutation">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
          <option value="">Ms</option>
          <option value="">Mr</option>
          <option value="">Mrs</option>
          <option value="">Doctor</option>
          <option value="">Prof</option>
        </select>
        <div class="form-control-focus">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="name">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text" name="first_name">
        <div class="form-control-focus">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="form_control_1">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text">
        <div class="form-control-focus">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="form_control_1">Mobile</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="phone_mobile" name="phone_mobile" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text">
        <div class="form-control-focus">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="form_control_1">Email Address</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" onchange="validateEmailAdd();">
        <div class="form-control-focus">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <button type="button" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn blue" id="submitButton" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <tr>
    <td style="display: none;">
      <input id="campaign_id" type="hidden" name="campaign_id" value="34101a86-12b1-bec3-2c18-560ed4c48ddb" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display: none;">
      <input id="assigned_user_id" type="hidden" name="assigned_user_id" value="1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display: none;">
      <input id="req_id" type="hidden" name="req_id" value="last_name;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

---

You are over-riding the function handler with your custom function, that **prevents the default action** of submitting the form.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This prevents the form from submitting. Here the `e` is the generated event, which is the form submission and the function `preventDefault()` prevents it from happening.

Generally this is used for AJAX based form submissions, where you submit the form, but actually, JavaScript sends the data to the server through AJAX. Hope this is clear enough. `:)`

An example of AJAX based form submission would be:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("url.php", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
        if (data = "okay")
            alert("Form is submitted!");
    });
});
```

For your issue, try giving this instead of calling the submit:

```
$("form").trigger("submit");
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I think the question was not clear. The problem is I'm not even seeing the alert.

Comment: @lemonTea Can you try this? `$('form').trigger("submit");`

Comment: @lemonTea Found the issue and updated the answer too. Can you kindly check this out, please?